# Getting Flask Error GET html 404 constantly

Tags: python, html, flask, web

All of my `.html` files are present in templates folder.

I'm getting a 404 error on one particular file called `tour1.html`

I have defined its route as:

```
@app.route('/tour1.html')
def tour1():
    return render_template('tour1.html')
```

Full Error is

```
"GET tour1.html HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Additionally, the linking works fine when I run on VS Code Live Server, so no issue in `html` files.

Here is what the project tree looks like

```
myproject\
      Data\
      fonts\
      GraphQL\
      js\
      Model\
      MongoDB\
      static\
            css\
            img\
      templates\
            404.html
            about.html
            contact.html
            aruserinterface.html
            index.html
            tour1.html
      main.py
```

this is code in main.py

```
from MongoDB.script import Mongodb
from MongoDB.mongo import query
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, redirect, render_template, url_for, send_from_directory
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import json, bson
import folium

mongoDb = Mongodb()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'db':'Cluster0', 'alias':'default'}

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/about.html')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/contact.html')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')
@app.route('/aruserinterface.html')
def aruserinterface():
    return render_template('aruserinterface.html')

@app.route('/tour1')
def tour1():
    return render_template('tour1.html')

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
  return render_template("404.html")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run('127.0.0.1', port=5100)
```

Comment: If the question is about ```flask```, why ```django``` tag ?

Comment: I suspect if `tour1.html` file is in `templates` folder?  Please recheck!

Comment: @Xitiz it is! just rechecked as well

Comment: @Ram because I've seen people raising same question for django, thought anyone with django knowledge could help as well :)

Comment: Post your complete code and folder structure as well.

Comment: @Ram okay done.

Comment: Does the other routes work - ```about```, ```contact``` etc ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing `tour1.html` in url but your route is just `tour1`.

If you're doing this :

```
@app.route('/tour1')
def tour1():
    return render_template('tour1.html')
```

Then you have to do `/tour1` in url rather then `tour1.html`.

If you want to do `/tour1.html` in url then you should do this:

```
@app.route('/tour1.html')
def tour1():
    return render_template('tour1.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the .html needs to be part of the route, check if this works:

```
@app.route('/tour1')  # removed the .html from the URL route definition
def tour1():
    return render_template('tour1.html')
```

if you're still getting a 404 error you should test the route using a curl command like this:

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5100/tour1"
```

or a more specialized tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)

Comment: I don't think `.html` in route is an issue!

Comment: It works fine even if ```.html``` is present in route. That's just a route.

Comment: its a 404 error so that means the url or resource can't be found on the server. .html isnt part of the route in any of the examples here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/views/ , so even if "it works", there's no point putting it there.

Comment: I have updated question with main.py code and project file structure, see if you can point out the issue now? @c8999c3f964f64

Comment: if you need to debug this further, change the code to return True or "Success", instead of rendering a template. This rules out a template error and should definitely work by using the curl command I posted in the answer. I dont see any other reason this would return a 404, it looks correct.

Comment: Got Success by returning "Success", this is weird why wont it return template then

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 i updated the html link from location.href('../templates/tour1.html') to location.href('tour1.html') and it worked somehow. now all links are being rendered. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh yeah, thats a routing issue after all then. You (or your user) is not supposed to link to the template, but the url you define in the app.route() function. Glad it works.

Comment: also, accept my answer or upvote the comments that helped you solve the problem : )

Comment: @RabiyaKhan have you ever mentioned anywhere in your question that you are doing _"location.href('../templates/tour1.html')"_ your error message says you are doing `tour1.html` and now from where you are saying you are doing that `/templates/tour1.html`. Please try to provide clear information in your question. If you don't provide correct information in question then our efforts will be useless like here mine I have answered but that is not the issue for you. You are doing completely different thing then I have thought.